# Gnuplot simple bar chart (histogram) from x-y data (x is uneven)

Tags: tuples, gnuplot, histogram, frequency

I have binned histogram data in this format:

```
BinCenter NumberOfOccurances
1 2
3 5
10 13
7 4
```

Notice the following:

1. Bins are not regularly spaced.
2. Bins are not sorted (though I could sort them).

I want gnuplot to plot a bar chart with this data.

I want vertical bars centered around BinCenter and the height of each bar should be the second-column value.

```
plot 'histo.txt' with boxes
```

does give me vertical bars, but the bars seem to be uneven in width.

Comment: as well as boxwidth you probably also need `set yrange [0:]` to see the first box.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for `set boxwidth`, which starts

```
The `set boxwidth` command is used to set the default width of boxes in the
 `boxes`, `boxerrorbars`, `boxplot`, `candlesticks` and `histograms` styles.

 Syntax:
       set boxwidth {<width>} {absolute|relative}
       show boxwidth

 By default, adjacent boxes are extended in width until they touch each other.
 A different default width may be specified using the `set boxwidth` command.
 `Relative` widths are interpreted as being a fraction of this default width.

 An explicit value for the boxwidth is interpreted as being a number of units
 along the current x axis (`absolute`) unless the modifier `relative` is given.
```